# Adding blank page to odd-paged PDF in Python

Tags: python, pypdf

This is a rewrite of [How to insert a "missing" page as blank page in PDF with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281468/how-to-insert-a-missing-page-as-blank-page-in-pdf-with-python) but I am trying to do it with the `PdfFileWriter` additional methods: `cloneDocumentFromReader()` and `addBlankPage()`, because it seemed cleaner this way.

I need to add a blank page at the end of PDF, if it contains odd number of pages, but the page count is larger than 1.

So I am trying to do this:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
with open(pdffile, 'rb') as input:
    pdf=PdfFileReader(input)
    numPages=pdf.getNumPages()
    if numPages > 1 and (numPages % 2 == 1):
            outPdf=PdfFileWriter()
            outPdf.cloneDocumentFromReader(pdf)
            outPdf.addBlankPage()
            outStream=file('/tmp/test.pdf','wb')
            outPdf.write(outStream)
            outStream.close()
```

The code works, but the PDF created is smaller than the original, and gives error (doesn't parse) when trying to open in Adobe Acrobat.

Do I mix up something with how this should work? I was a bit surprised when I saw I couldn't navigate in Pdf with PdfWriter to choose where to add blank page, but I assumed, after I have cloned the document, it should have some internal "marker" at the end page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, it turns out I did need another method. Namely `PdfWriter.appendPagesFromReader()` .